# Dynamic imports not working after vite build

Tags: javascript, vite

I'm trying to build a component plugin system with vite bundler.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import { loadPlugins } from './pluginLoader.js';
loadPlugins(false);
```

**pluginLoader.js**

```
const pluginsConfig = {
  "plugins": [

    {
      "name": "myButton",
      "path": "./components/debug/myButton/myButton.js",
      "enabled": true,
      "buttonDomOrder": 2
    }
  ]
}

const loadPlugins = (parentsOnly = false) => {
  const initializationPromises = [];

  for (const pluginConfig of pluginsConfig.plugins) {
    if (!pluginConfig.enabled) continue;

    // Check condition based on parentsOnly flag
    if ((parentsOnly && pluginConfig.createsParentDOM) || (!parentsOnly && !pluginConfig.createsParentDOM)) {
      const initializationPromise = import(pluginConfig.path /* @vite-ignore */).then((module) => {       
        if (module.initialize) {
          return module.initialize(pluginConfig.buttonDomOrder);
        }
      });

      initializationPromises.push(initializationPromise);
    }
  }

  return initializationPromises;
};

export { loadPlugins };
```

**./components/debug/myButton/myButton.js**

```
const initialize = async (buttonDomOrder) => {
    console.log("Initializing myButton Component")
};


export { initialize };
```

While this is working with vite dev server it is not when building the app but failing with

```
   GET http://localhost:8000/assets/components/debug/myButton/myButton.js 404 (File not found)
```

I've tried to used alias and the dynamicImport Plugin without luck

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import dynamicImport from 'vite-plugin-dynamic-import';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
plugins: [
    dynamicImport()
    ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'components'), 
    },
  },
});
```

**My question is:**

What can I do so that vite understands my dynamic imports and respects them in a build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vite doesn't support directories with variables in dynamic import:
https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import

To avoid this kind of problems you can use a "loader" function like in `vue-router`:

```
const pluginsConfig = {
  "plugins": [

    {
      "name": "myButton",
      "component": () => import("./components/debug/myButton/myButton.js"),
      "enabled": true,
      "buttonDomOrder": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It looks this is what I was looking for. You made my day! thanks a million!